# How do I use Macros to copy select data from one worksheet to another on Excel?

Tags: excel-2010

I need to create a Macro on Excel to keep track of changing contracts. There's already an existing macro that updates the contract data so I need to create another macro...

There are two worksheets. On the first worksheet is a bunch of data with each row representing one contract. There are several categories (Contract #, Date, Price, etc.).

I need to write a Macro that finds only certain contracts fitting specific criteria (like, contacts at a specific date or a certain price), copies and pastes them into the second worksheet.

What I've done so far:
I've figured out a bit of a convoluted way of doing it using IF and OR functions. So using OR I specify the criteria and IF to basically find the corresponding data if things are TRUE.

When things are false, a 0 is entered. The problem is I have tons of rows of zeroes---rows/contracts that didn't fit the criteria. When I try to use the find command (CTRL+F) to find, highlight, and properly delete (with rows shifted up) all the zeroes, Macro doesn't record it and I'm not sure how to write it in the code.

Any insight would help!

Comment: These IF and OR functions you're using... are in VBA or directly in Excel? If they're in VBA, would you mind to share the code you have now?

Comment: They're directly in Excel. It's just a regular IF & OR...
=IF(OR(TermSheet!$E40=41220,TermSheet!$M40="bpxx"),TermSheet!E40,0)

Comment: Is there any reason to not apply a filter to pick the zeroed rows and get rid of them all? I believe it could work even using the macro recording functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Just change your formula to:

```
=IF(OR(TermSheet!$E40=41220,TermSheet!$M40="bpxx"),TermSheet!E40,"")
```